# PHP Friend Relationship between 2 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, relationship, friend

first time I've used this site .. I've had a good look around but I cant seem to find the answer to my question. It's been answered in other ways but not for what I want I think..

Image of the database table so it's easy to see: http://puu.sh/6BtmZ.png

So basically I've got a friends.php page that has an input field and submit button, you put a username in and press submit and I want it to send a request to that user; I've got that to work, the user can accept but it only places the "friend" into him. As in FRIENDA is friends with FRIENDB but on FRIENDB's page he isn't friends with FRIENDA .. I hope this makes sense.

I just basically want it so, you send a request and the person accepts it and BOTH parties can see each other as friends.

```
 <?php 
include 'core/init.php';
// check
protect_page();
include 'includes/templates/header.php'; 

$user_id = $user_data['user_id'];

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username');

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username to send a request!';
            break 1;
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . htmlentities($_POST['username']) . '\' doesn\'t exist.';
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Friend request sent!';
} else {

if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    // add friend
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $get_userid = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get_userid);
    $username_id = $row[user_id];   
    $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_friends` (user_id, friends_with) VALUES ('$user_id', '$username_id')");

    //redirect
    header('location: friends.php?success');
    //exit
    exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        // output errors
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
}
?>

<h1>Friends</h1>
<p>
<h2>Send a friend request:</h2>
    <form id="friend_request" action="" method="POST">
        <ul>
            <li>Username: <input type="text" name="username"><input id="friend_request" type="submit"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</p>

<p>
<h2>Pending requests:</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['decline'])){
$decline_id = $_POST['decline_friend_id'];  
$decline_query = "DELETE FROM `users_friends` WHERE `id` = $decline_id"; 
$accept_result = mysql_query($decline_query);
}

if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
       $accept_id = $_POST['accept_friend_id'];  
       $accept_query = "UPDATE `users_friends` SET `request_pending` = 0 WHERE `id` = $accept_id"; 
       $accept_result = mysql_query($accept_query);     
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_friends` WHERE `friends_with` = '$user_id' AND `request_pending` = 1");

while($requests_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $get_username = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$requests_row[user_id]'");
    $get_username_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_username);
    $request_from = $get_username_row[username];

    echo 'Request from: ' . $request_from . '<form id="decline" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="decline_friend_id" value="' . $requests_row['id'] . '">
                        <input type="submit" value="Decline" name="decline">
                        </form>
                        <form id="accept" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="accept_friend_id" value="' . $requests_row['id'] . '">
                        <input type="submit" value="Accept" name="accept">
                        </form>';
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
</p>

<h2>Your friends:</h2>
<?php
$friends_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_friends` WHERE `friends_with` = '$user_id' AND `request_pending` = 0");
while($friends_row = mysql_fetch_array($friends_result)) {
    $get_username = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$friends_row[user_id]'");
    $get_username_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_username);
    $friend = $get_username_row[username];

    echo $friend . '<br />';
    }
    ?>
    </p>

    <?php include 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

Hopefully someone might be able to help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is insert both directions in the friends relationship once both friends have confirmed.  So instead of doing this:

```
INSERT INTO `users_friends` (user_id, friends_with) VALUES ('$user_id', '$username_id')
```

You would do this:

```
INSERT INTO `users_friends` (user_id, friends_with) VALUES ('$user_id', '$username_id'),('$username_id','$user_id')
```

This would allow you to do the friend lookup in either direction.

What is unclear to me however is how you store pending friend requests in your database. So what you may ultimately need to do is to insert those relations in the DB and then simply update those DB records to change the value of an "accepted" flag once the friendship has confirmed.

Comment: Thanks to you too, this sounds more like what I want, although I've never done a query like that. Although I am just getting into PHP so I'll give it ago!

Comment: Okay, just tried it and it all works. It adds 2 rows that are basically in reverse which is good. Although it comes up as a pending request for me as well as the other person. 

What I've got is if you "accept" the request (which is just a list if "pending = 1") which will change to 0 meaning they're your friend. How do I go about making it send the request but not to myself? Also perhaps deleting, as if I remove the friend I want it to remove both entries.

Comment: @user3245541 Deleting is the same concept: `DELETE FROM users_friends WHERE (user_id = $user_id AND friends_with = $username_id) OR (friends_with = $user_id AND user_id = $username_id)`  I am not sure what your logic is about sending a request, but obviously you would just filter out the cases where the user id in the table is the same as the user's user id.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of "users_friends" table looks like this:

```
me        friends_with      request_pending
```

to get the result (= if the user is your friend):

```
"SELECT * FROM `users_friends` WHERE (`friends_with` = '$user_id' AND `me`= `$me`) OR (`friends_with` = '$me' AND `me`= `$user_id `) AND `request_pending` = 0"
```

You check if the user is in `friends_with` where YOU are in `me`.. or if the user is in `me` and you're in `friends_with`

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it makes sense now and I'll give it ago! :)